# rewriterules remove .php in the middle of url

Tags: url-rewriting

I'm having trouble rewriting url from `/video.php/test-video` to `/video/test-video`

I currently use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^/video/(.*)$ /video.php?/$1 [L]
```

I already `rewrite index.php/url-with-white-list` to `/url-with-white-list`.
Now I've had a video.php file that uses url from a database.

I just would like to rewrite `video.php/url-of-the-video` to `video/url-of-the-video` to

My rewrite of index.php works but I can't make my rewrite of video.php works.

Any ideas ?

By advance, thanks a lot !

Any suggestion ?

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^(.*)video/(.*)
RewriteRule (.*)video/(.*)$ /video.php?/$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```